# Finding the largest number in a [String: [Int]] Swift dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am new in Swift.
I have an error with this code and I can't find any answer on this site.
I print largest number but I want to print largest number's kind.

```
let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime": [2,3,5,7,11,13],
    "Fibonacci": [1,1,2,3,5,8,13],
    "Square": [1,4,9,16,25,36]
]

var largestNumber = 0

for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for x in numbers {
        for y in kind {
            if x > largestNumber {
                largestNumber = x
            }
        }
    }
}

print("the largest number is = \(largestNumber)")
```

Comment: i want to write kind of largest number or smaller numbers kind too ...etc

Comment: If my answer really solved your issue, pls remember to accept it when you get a chance... thanks bro!

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
var largestNumber = 0
var largestNumberKind: String!

for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for x in numbers {
        if x > largestNumber {
            largestNumber = x
            largertNumberKind = kind
        }
    }
}

print("the largest number is = \(largestNumber)")
print("the largest number kind is = \(largestNumberKind)")
```

Regarding your original code:

- you were only keeping track of the largest number, losing the kind info you wanted. The `largestNumberKind` variable I added does just that.
- looping over the `kind: String` didn't make any sense (the `for y in kind` line). Your outside loop already iterates a key at a time, so such inner loop is pointless.

Comment: You should explain what was wrong and how this fixes it.

Comment: I don't recommend that `largestNumberKind` be `String!` here. That invites crashing if `interestingNumbers` is empty, which seems inappropriate. I think it is correctly `String?`. Also, this will fail if the maximum value is negative. I believe you want to initialize `largestNumber` to `Int.min`.

Comment: @RobNapier Makes sense, *if* he were asking for a industrial strength, production ready algorithm. But he clearly stated he is new to Swift and, as such, I explicitly tried to minimize *conceptual weight* (not always an easy task, one may say). For instance, having to learn non-implicit optionals just to hack together a homework is just overkill IMHO. Sometimes you really need to learn a trick at time ;-) Anyway, thanks a lot for the detailed feedback man... that's why I keep coming back to SO :)

Comment: @tombulbu Hey man, don't forget to accept my answer when you get a chance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with Paulo's approach (with some minor corrections; see comments there), but this is a reasonable problem to explore more functional approaches that don't require looping and mutation.

For example, we can just flatten each kind to its maximum element (or `Int.min` if it's empty), then take the kind with the highest max:

```
interestingNumbers
    .map { (kind: $0, maxValue: $1.max() ?? .min) } // Map each kind to its max value
    .max { $0.maxValue < $1.maxValue }?             // Find the kind with the max value
    .kind                                           // Return the kind
```

This does create a slight edge condition that I don't love. If you evaluate the following:

```
let interestingNumbers = [
    "ImaginaryReals": [],
    "Smallest": [Int.min],
]
```

It's not well defined here which will be returned. Clearly the correct answer is "Smallest," but it's kind of order-dependent. With a little more thought (and code) we can fix this. The problem is that we are taking a little shortcut by treating an empty list as having an `Int.min` maximum (this also prevents our system from working for things like `Float`, so that's sad). So let's fix that. Let's be precise. The `max` of an empty list is `nil`. We want to drop those elements.

We can use a modified version of `mapValues` (which is [coming in Swift 4](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0165-dict.md#3-dictionary-specific-map-and-filter) I believe). We'll make `flatMapValues`:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func flatMapValues<T>(_ transform: (Value) throws -> T?) rethrows -> [Key: T] {
        var result: [Key: T] = [:]

        for (key, value) in self {
            if let newValue = try transform(value) {
                result[key] = newValue
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

And with that, we can be totally precise, even with empty lists in the mix:

```
interestingNumbers
    .flatMapValues { $0.max() }
    .max { $0.1 < $1.1 }?
    .key
```

Again, nothing wrong with Paulo's approach if you find it clear, but there are other ways of thinking about the problem.

BTW, the equivalent version that iterates would look like this:

```
var largestNumber: Int? = nil
var largestNumberKind: String? = nil

for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for x in numbers {
        if largestNumber == nil || largestNumber! < x {
            largestNumber = x
            largestNumberKind = kind
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice write up! I was working on a pure functional version myself but you beat me to it :) All in all, I think I *still* prefer the iterative version... and it might perform better too (assuming the compiler doesn't pull any non-trivial functional optimization trick on me).

Comment: And I agree that `Int?` feels more idiomatic than using `Int.min`. The latter approach feels like a C style hack, not really on par with Swift's richer type system.